# Problem with scikeo, typeError'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int

Tags: python, image-classification

I am trying to use scikeo as a package to classify optical images from Satellite. Below I have put a script in which there is an error, but I don't know what the solution is.

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from scikeo.mla import MLA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dbfread import DBF
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
path_raster = r"satellite_image.tif"
img = rasterio.open(path_raster)

path_endm = r"file_from_shape.dbf"
endm = DBF(path_endm)

# endmembers
df = pd.DataFrame(iter(endm))
df.head()

inst = MLA(image = img, endmembers = endm)
```

The error is: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`
Below there is Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):



Cell In[11], line 18
    inst = MLA(image = img, endmembers = endm)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\image_march\lib\site-packages\scikeo\mla.py:92 in __init__
    if all(self.endm.iloc[:,int(i)] < 100) & all(self.endm.iloc[:,int(i)] >= 0): indx = i; break

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\image_march\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py:72 in new_method
    return method(self, other)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\image_march\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py:50 in __lt__
    return self._cmp_method(other, operator.lt)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\image_march\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:6243 in _cmp_method
    res_values = ops.comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\image_march\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:287 in comparison_op
    res_values = comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, lvalues, rvalues)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\image_march\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:75 in comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY
    result = libops.scalar_compare(x.ravel(), y, op)

  File pandas\_libs\ops.pyx:107 in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_compare

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: When I run the last line, I have error.

Comment: now there is also traceback